# Copying Library Design, not data?

Tags: sharepoint-library

Rather than recreate a current library, I need to duplicate the design and move to another SP location (with no content). I have Designer 2013 and SP admin. Is there a simple, straight-forward approach?

Comment: How did you apply the design?

Comment: A little more detail would be helpful please...what do you mean by design? Custom columns, advanced settings, etc.? Are you using custom content types? Special forms?

Comment: I want the exact set up (custom columns, etc.) but without copying data and design.  I realize I could create a new app and just rebuild the design, but was looking for shortcuts, if available

Answer (score 1):

Go to the list settings and click "Save document library as template." It will then give you the option to save with or without content. When finished, it will link you to the file. Download the file and upload it at the corresponding link on your new site. Then you'll be able to create a new library from the template.